# Hibernate criteria how to not load the children childrens

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Hello I have three entityes user,candidate(jobseeker) and interview. I want to load an interview with candidate, but with candidate it loads the user. I tried to resolve from annotiation putting lazy to jobseeker-user relation it works but when I want to load a jobseeker with user gives no proxy session. I think I must to resolve somehow from the criteria.

My interview entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "INTERVIEW")
    public class Interview extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", nullable=false)
    @Expose
    @NotNull
    private Job job;

    /** candidates for interview */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_seeker_id", nullable=false)
    @Expose
    @NotNull
    private JobSeeker candidate;
    .
    .
    .
```

JobSeeker entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="JOB_SEEKER") 
    public class JobSeeker extends BaseEntity{

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    .
    .
    .
```

User entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="USER_AUTH")
    public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private JobSeeker jobSeeker;
    .
    .
    .
```

And the criteria:

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session
    .createCriteria(Interview.class, "interview")
    .setFirstResult(dataTableFilter.iDisplayStart)
    .setMaxResults(dataTableFilter.iDisplayLength)
    .createAlias("interview.candidate", "candidate");
```

Now it is working but for n interview makes n query because of user, when I put lazy in jobseeker-user writes 1 query but I cant put lazy there. I searched on stackoverlow and I see lazy loading like

```
.setFetchMode("candidate.user", FetchMode.SELECT)
```

or

```
.setFetchMode("candidate.user", FetchMode.LAZY)
```

but it did not worked for me, it writes also n query. Can I somehow tell in criteria to not load the user child with jobSeeker, or an other option for lazy load the user?

**SOLUTION:**
With projection I resolved now my criteria looks like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session
        .createCriteria(Interview.class, "interview")
        .setFirstResult(dataTableFilter.iDisplayStart)
        .setMaxResults(dataTableFilter.iDisplayLength)
        .createAlias("interview.job", "job")
        .createAlias("interview.candidate", "candidate"))
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                .add(Projections.property("status"), "status")
                .add(Projections.property("date"), "date")
                .add(Projections.property("candidate.name"), "candidate.name"))
                    .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(Interview.class));
```

Now selects just the interview id,status,date and the candidate name. The simple AliasToBeanTransformer did not work for candidate.name and I found a nice transformer witch works. Link: https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer

Comment: You understand that the error when you're using lazyness is because you are traying to access a Hibernate proxy outside the session and so Hibernate can't initialize the proxy?

Comment: Yeah I understend, but how I write in the solution update works, did not want to load the user or the full candidate object just the candidate name and thats enought for me:)

Answer (score 2):

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();

Criteria criteria = session
.createCriteria(Interview.class, "interview")
.setFirstResult(dataTableFilter.iDisplayStart)
.setMaxResults(dataTableFilter.iDisplayLength)
.createAlias("interview.candidate", "candidate")
.createAlias("candidate.user",  JoinType.NONE);
```

Also you can set projections additional to this criteria

Comment: Hello this did not work for me it wirtes even more query with .createAlias("candidate.user",  JoinType.NONE); Now I am reading after projections hope it will solve my problem

Comment: Ok.. it worked for me when I used createCriteria instead of createAlias

Comment: I tried with criteria to but it was the same, also  thanks for the answer